# Tkinter - Removing n nameless Labels

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, label

I will try to exemplify as much as possible.
I am developing a program in which I have data recorded in a database.db and access it through the `SQLite3` library. I created a function to return the data for a specific column that I want and it will be several Labels with the data returned.
In this program I use the `.pack()` method and I know that if I use the `pack_forget()` command, the `Label` will be removed from the window with every new query I make.
The problem is that as there are several Labels for each data returned, I do not create names for each Label and now I have this problem. For each search, I want to remove all Labels for the newest search. How can I remove Labels from the window if they do not have a variable name. Below is an example:

```py
def clear():
    # ???
    Label.pack_forget()

def search(v):
    # 'v' cames from Entry's textvariable
    tmp4Label = []

    var4Len = list(c.execute(
        f'SELECT * FROM table WHERE element = "{v.get()}"').fetchall())

    for i in range(len(var4Len)):
        # Getting just the first column data
        #'c' is the cursor
        a.append(list(c.execute(
            f'SELECT * FROM table WHERE element = "{v.get()}"').fetchall())[i][0])

    for i in tmp4Label:
        # Labels for each data, removing '[' and ']' characters
        Label(root, text=f"{str([i]).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')}",font=('Arial 18 bold')).pack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to store the Labels in a list:

```
list_of_labels = []

def clear():
    while list_of_labels:
        list_of_labels.pop().pack_forget() # remove from the list

def search(v):
    for i in tmp4Label:
        lbl = Label(root, text=i)
        lbl.pack()
        list_of_labels.append(lbl) # add to the list
```

Another solution is to use a single label instead of a stack of them.

```
def clear():
    data_label.pack_forget() 

def search(v):
    global data_label
    data_label = Label(root, text='\n'.join(map(str, tmp4Label)))
    data_label.pack()
```

Whatever you do it's extremely important to use 2 lines to define the Label. The first to define it, the second to lay it out (pack it). You cannot combine those 2 lines.

Comment: That’s a good idea, to make individual items semi-anonymous. Thanks